# Mark Salesforce Custom Trigger as Inactive using SOAP/REST APIs in C#

Tags: c#, rest, api, soap, salesforce

I have some triggers written in Salesforce, for example: InsertContactData, UpdateContactData, DeleteContactData. Using C# and (SOAP/REST) API, I want to send data to salesforce (where these triggers are deployed and active) to inactive a trigger (for example, UpdateContactData), then I will perform some task on the Org, and would then set Trigger to Active state, once all the work is completed.

Algorithm of my Code Execution:

1. Deploy code on Developer Salesforce org (where triggers are active) (Note: Trigger metadata file cannot be updated here, since the code changes are not allowed. But I can view code.)
2. Disable some triggers using API with C#
3. Perform some operations on Org
4. Enable triggers (which are disabled in Step 2) using API with C#

I did referred the Salesforce Tooling API and tried to implement it, but it restricts updates on Metadata of Trigger.

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer these Links

http://www.vinaychaturvedi.com/blog/apex-triggers-in-salesforce/

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

```
Trigger.isExecuting ()
```

Returns true if the current context for the Apex code is a trigger, not a Visualforce page, a Web service, or an executeanonymous() API call.

Comment: Thank you, @Sudarshan. But, actually what I am looking for is an API Call from C# Code, just to disable or enable the Trigger. Sorry if the question was not clear.